# Oracle Large Objects storage in blocks

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

In Oracle data storage, if the size of each block is from 2 KB to 32 KB, how do Oracle store the CLOB/BLOB data types as the size of the CLOB/BLOBS might be in several MB's?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"the size of the CLOB/BLOBS might be in several MB's"* or even GBs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two modes of LOB storage: inline and out-of-line. Inline means the data is stored as part of the record. Out-of-line means the data is stored in a separate location dedicated to storing LOBs.

This is covered in the documentation ([find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADLOB/adlob_tables.htm#ADLOB45273)) but the main takeaway is that only LOB values of <4000 bytes can be stored inline; anything larger is stored out-of-line.

> [LOB is] 1GB, and a block size is 32KB, will it store that 1GB data in 1048576 inner-linked database blocks

Yes. That's why it's important to specify the CHUNK size correctly (at least if you're using BasicFile storage). Chunks are multiples of tablespace blocks: it is more efficient to store large LOBs in big chunks but if you have lots of small LOBs you'll be wasting space.